# j2me+print the number in decremental form in form

Tags: java, java-me

i m working in j2me.Please help me.
I had used the below code:-

```
 protected void startApp() {
            display = Display.getDisplay(this);

            form = new Form("Item Layout");            
                      TxtData=new TextField("Number","" , 4, TextField.NUMERIC);
            GO = new Command("Go", Command.OK, 1);
            Exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);
            form.append(TxtData);

            form.addCommand(GO);
            form.addCommand(Exit);
            form.setCommandListener(this);
            display.setCurrent(form);        


    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    notifyDestroyed();
    }

    public void commandAction(Command cmnd, Displayable dsplbl) {
    String label = cmnd.getLabel();
  if(label.equals("Go")){
    number=Integer.parseInt(TxtData.getString());
    timer = new Timer();
  task = new TestTimerTask();
  timer.schedule(task,500,500); 
  } else if(label.equals("Exit")){
      destroyApp(true);
    }

    }

  private class TestTimerTask extends TimerTask{
  public final void run(){        
  number--;  
  form.append(""+ number+"\n");

  if(number==0){
  timer.cancel();
  }
  }
    }
```

And my output is in :-[image]

But i want it in this way:-

instead of printing number in series.. in want the only single decremented number to be printed.

Like only 6 in screen
then only 5 in screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a `StringItem` add it to form and set the no to it in task and play with it instead of appending the String each time.

**See**

- [Example of StringItem](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/StringItemDemo.htm)